# How to solve SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I have created two tables in database which are the employers table and users table. When i tried to login as employer, the error appeared like this

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'emp_email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `emp_email` = zadtar@gmail.com limit 1)
```

i noticed that the sql is searching the data from users table instead of the employers table. How do i fix this error?

this is my login function in employer controller

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if(!\Auth::attempt(['emp_email' => $request->emp_email,'password' => $request->password])){
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return redirect()->route('dashboardEmployer');     
    }
```

this is my login part in employerlogin.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login-employer') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <input id="emp_email" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('emp_email') ? ' is-invalid' : 
     '' }}" 
     name="emp_email" value="{{ old('emp_email') }}" 
     required autocomplete="emp_email" 
     autofocus placeholder="Email Address">

           @if ($errors->has('emp_email'))
               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('emp_email') }}</strong>
               </span>
           @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Show your ‘Auth’ model

Comment: do you change config > auth.php file ? laravel authentication system gets the user data from the database, since the default setting to authenticate against users table, you need to add the provider for employers table. create provider then new guard in your login-controller overwrite the overwite the guard function and use your new guard

Answer (score 0):

> All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
>       users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
>       mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
>       If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
>       sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
>       be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.

This is what Taylor said in config->auth.
All you need to do is add tables or models which you want to recognized for catching users:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Here App\Models\User::class is the default model to retrieve users; But you can add more tables or change the default.